How to get data feed for eth to usd, to add information in solidity
How can I get solidity code for getting latest eth-usd price update to add in solidity/remix? I am just a beginner. I have tried chain link data feed, but its only giving data for btc-usd
I want to get data feeds for eth-usd, but i am only getting BTC-USd latest data

You need to search for ETH/USD on the Chainlink Price Feed Contract Addresses page, and then use that corresponding price feed address in your contract depending on the network.


The sample codes for data feed are provided in Chainlink official document
As you said, the data feed address provided in the sample codes is BTC/USD (0x1b44F3514812d835EB1BDB0acB33d3fA3351Ee43) on Ethereum sepolia testnet, and you can find other feed addresses in this page.
Hope it helps.
